# div height not expanding with browser

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a content editable div inside another div. The width expands when IE is expanded, but height is not expanding
I set a min-height of 300px because i want it to be 300 px height at the time of loading, but when making IE taller, the div stays with same height.
I really want it to grow along with IE size.

My aspx

```
 <div id="divLeftTable" clientidmode="Static" runat="server">
    <div id="divQuerytextarea" contenteditable="true" class="inputQryclass" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

My css

```
    .inputQryclass
{
    border:1px;
    border-style:solid; 
    overflow:auto; 
    border-color:Silver; 
    height: auto !important;
    height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    /*width:180%;*/
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: IE size? you mean the window size? did you try height: 100%?

Comment: @Ayyash that doesn't seem to work either, for some reason.

Comment: why do you have height: auto? this only makes height accommodate content inside div, not span the wnidow

Comment: height:100% should go to the heighest div in the hierarchy, the closest to body element, otherwise the height will be relative to the parent div which must have height defined in pixels

Comment: height:auto is to override height . height is here for IE6 wich applies it as min-height.

Comment: tried adding/removing height:auto/height:100%, gave body 100% height. nothing helped

Answer (score 1):

1. `height : auto;` is *not* equivalent to `height: 100%;`
2. `height: 100%;` means that the element takes 100% of the height of    its parent, not of the full window.

For your div to take 100% of the screen, all its parent must take 100% too. That means `<html>` and `<body>` element, too.

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XF4FM/).

Also note that a height of 100% does not means to take all avalaible place. Like in the fiddle, it can result in scrollbars due to borders, margins, etc.

EDIT
`height : auto;` will make your div adjust to its content, not to the size of the window.

Comment: I believe he wants to have a min-height and expand if neede :)

Answer (score 0):

I see no problemes
http://jsfiddle.net/9WcAW/show/

IF ms-IE involved, did you check that you have a valid doctype ?
like this one ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

height and min-height are correctly used.(it includes IE6 behavior) It might be some more CSS overriding it in your page. Stand-alone works fine.

Comment: Ah ? , wich browser/OS is involved ? Works form me in IE8/9, safari, chrome, FF, Opera. latest.

Comment: IE9 and win 7. I open uo ur link. Restore the window to a normal size and drag the bottom side of the window down... the div's heigh does not change. If i drag the right side of the window towards more right, the div's width increases. So i face problem with only height

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
    .inputQryclass
{
    position: absolute;
    border:1px;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-color:Silver;
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 96%;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: 96%;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: position: absolute helps but there are other controls in the page and they kinda come inside this div area

Comment: There sould be no proble for the contents. They can be set relative to dis div.